# deploying play2 app on cludbees

Tags: deployment, playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I've a play app on my system created using eclipse .How can I deploy it on cluodbees.I'm not able to follow the tutorial given on cloudbees website.Please provide link to some easy to follow tutorial if available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be interested in this guide:

http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

The steps you should follow are pretty simple for a play 2 application.

1. Download and install the [CoudBees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK)
2. Create a blank application

   $bees app:create -t play2 -a appName
3. Create a database

   $bees db:create dbName
4. Bind the application to the database

   $bees app:bind -a appName -db dbName -as mydb
5. Deploy your application

   $bees app:deploy -a appName -t play2 PATH_TO_WAR_FILE.zip

Application configuration (for binding with the database):

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:"${DATABASE_URL_DB}
db.default.user=${DATABASE_USERNAME_DB}
db.default.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD_DB}
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=10
db.default.partitionCount=2
```